# Slow connection on wired Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15) on Manjaro

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, ethernet

I'm running KDE Manjaro with the 5.8 linux kernel and I have the Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15) network board. The speed never goes up 40MB/s, while the wireless on the same network goes to 120MB/s. I tried installing the `r8168` driver and blacklisting the `r8169` kernel module, without any affect. IPV6 is disabled. Any ideas on what can be done to increase speed?

Comment: Try another cable?

Comment: Tried that. Same problem.

Comment: What else is involved in your speedtest?  With the same card and the r8169 pilot, I get 76MB/s for an scp from another system with a direct link.

Comment: Either using direct copy from another server using scp or rsync, or https://fast.com, or https://speedtest.net, they all perform more or less the same: 1/3 of the max speed of 120Mb/s that I can get with Wifi over the same router and same ISP to the same locations.

Comment: Do you have another system with a GB NIC which you could connect to via cable?

Comment: Yes, also tested that. 120 MB/s on the same router. I'm getting convinced that the problem is the NIC driver.

Comment: No, I'd like you to test without router: the two systems back to back.  Also, a problem with that driver?  You're really not the only one using it.  What about network parameters?  What if another system had the same IP address?

Comment: Just tested on a different computer, wiht cable, on the same router port, same IP, and the same cable, on the same router and it worked great, so the only thing that changed is the ethernet port on the problematic computer. And yes, it seems that r8169/r1868 driver has lots of problems on Linux.

Comment: Yes, it seems people may forget to install firmware.

Comment: Yes, and that's not the case here. I tried using the standard one, and the ones compiled from AUR, no luck.